# CryptoAPI returns incorrect result for HMAC_SHA1

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, cryptoapi, hmacsha1

I'm using the code below with the Crypto API and I'm not getting the results I would expect based on testing with other API's and libraries.

I'm using the key, "**key**" and the data is "**message**"

For example, using Indy's TidHMACSHA1, I get 2088df74d5f2146b48146caf4965377e9d0be3a4

I get the same result using online generators (such as http://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html, for example).

With the code I've written (see below) I get 4a52c3c0abc0a06049d1ab648bb4057e3ff5f359

The code is below, I'm using the JEDI wcrypt2.pas header

```
function Hashhmacsha1(const Key, Value: AnsiString): AnsiString;
var
  hCryptProvider: HCRYPTPROV;
  hHash: HCRYPTHASH;
  hKey: HCRYPTKEY;
  bHash: array[0..$7F] of Byte;
  dwHashLen: dWord;
  i: Integer;


  hHmacHash: HCRYPTHASH;
  bHmacHash: array[0..$7F] of Byte;
  dwHmacHashLen: dWord;
  hmac_info : Wcrypt2.HMAC_INFO;
begin
  dwHashLen := 32;
  dwHmacHashLen := 32;
  {get context for crypt default provider}
  if CryptAcquireContext(@hCryptProvider, nil, nil, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT or CRYPT_MACHINE_KEYSET) then
  begin
    {create hash-object }
    if CryptCreateHash(hCryptProvider, CALG_SHA1, 0, 0, @hHash) then
    begin

      {get hash from password}
      if CryptHashData(hHash, @Key[1], Length(Key), 0) then
      begin

        // hHash is now a hash of the provided key, (SHA1)
        // Now we derive a key for it
        if CryptDeriveKey(hCryptProvider, CALG_RC4, hHash, 0, @hKey) then
        begin

          //hkey now holds our key. So we have do the whole thing over again
          //ZeroMemory( hmac_info, SizeOf(hmac_info) );
          hmac_info.HashAlgid := CALG_SHA1;
          if CryptCreateHash(hCryptProvider, CALG_HMAC, hKey, 0, @hHmacHash) then
          begin

            {get hash from password}

              if CryptSetHashParam( hHmacHash, HP_HMAC_INFO, @hmac_info, 0) then
              begin

                if CryptHashData(hHmacHash, @Value[1], Length(Value), 0) then
                begin
                  if CryptGetHashParam(hHmacHash, HP_HASHVAL, @bHmacHash[0], @dwHmacHashLen, 0) then
                  begin
                    for i := 0 to dwHmacHashLen-1 do
                      Result := Result + IntToHex(bHmacHash[i], 2);
                  end
                  else
                   WriteLn( 'CryptGetHashParam ERROR --> ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)) ;
                end
                else
                  WriteLn( 'CryptHashData ERROR --> ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)) ;
                {destroy hash-object}
                CryptDestroyHash(hHmacHash);
                CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
              end
              else
                WriteLn( 'CryptSetHashParam ERROR --> ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)) ;

          end
          else
            WriteLn( 'CryptCreateHash ERROR --> ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)) ;
        end
        else
          WriteLn( 'CryptDeriveKey ERROR --> ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)) ;

      end;
      {destroy hash-object}
      CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
    end;
    {release the context for crypt default provider}
    CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProvider, 0);
  end;
  Result := AnsiLowerCase(Result);
end;
```

I'm obviously doing something incorrectly, but I'm no idea what ??

Comment: When I see questions like this, the first thing I think is "because Unicode issues."  But it looks like you're using AnsiStrings, so that wouldn't actually be the source of the problem here...

Comment: Yeah, i considered that, which why I'm using AnsiStrings - so I have a somewhat valid comparision. Doesn't seem to have helped !!

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help but all hashing algorithms work on binary data. And in your case you are providing it with a null terminated string (Delphi strings are null terminated strings). This probably means that it also uses that nul character on the end of the string when calculating the hash. So you might wanna use array of ansi chars as input value instead of default Delphi ansi string.

Comment: @SilverWarior Thanks for the suggestion, but I've already found that isn't the issue here. I'm posting an answer which works, kinda off...

Comment: You should stop treating string buffers as binary. Convert a Unicode string to, say, utf8 bytes and hash that.

Comment: @David Heffernan, I disagree based on previous experience with other implementations. What you're suggestion would result in encoding problems and incorrect hashes because of that.

Comment: Not so. It's your approach that suffers from that. In your approach your hash function is a function of the input text and the local code page. Not what you intend. I have no idea why so many Delphi programmers seem incapable of understanding that text is not binary. The other language where this misconception is rife is PHP which says something I suppose.

Comment: I have to disagree, its exactly as i intend. If the input was unicode, sure you'd have a point. But it isnt. This code has to work against several other implementations (over which i have no control) which use ansi. You've made an assumption, which in other scenarios may be valid, but not this one. You will notice one of the first things pointed out was encoding which is not an issue here. Granted, we should be using unicode, but a hash of the same string characters but once in ansi and once in unicode generates entirely different hashes for a very good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a solution, which when generating an HMAC_SHA1 for the data "message" with the key "key" generates the expected hash of 2088df74d5f2146b48146caf4965377e9d0be3a4

As you can see, this code uses `CryptImportKey` instead of `CryptDeriveKey`, which seems to resolve the issue. It seems that using CryptDeriveKey is actually generating an HMAC_SHA1 hash using the data "message" and the SHA1 Hash of the key "key" encoded as RC4 instead of the plaintext key as initially thought.

The code works for keys upto 16 characters in length, any larger and only uses the first 16 characters anyway. I'm posting a second quesiton to enquire about that!!

Code is posted below.

```
function Hashhmacsha1(const Key, Value: AnsiString): AnsiString;
const
  KEY_LEN_MAX = 16;
var
  hCryptProvider: HCRYPTPROV;
  hHash: HCRYPTHASH;
  hKey: HCRYPTKEY;
  bHash: array[0..$7F] of Byte;
  dwHashLen: dWord;
  i: Integer;

  hPubKey : HCRYPTKey;
  hHmacHash: HCRYPTHASH;
  bHmacHash: array[0..$7F] of Byte;
  dwHmacHashLen: dWord;
  hmac_info : Wcrypt2.HMAC_INFO;

  keyBlob: record
    keyHeader: BLOBHEADER;
    keySize: DWORD;
    keyData: array[0..KEY_LEN_MAX-1] of Byte;
  end;
  keyLen : INTEGER;
begin
  dwHashLen := 32;
  dwHmacHashLen := 32;
  {get context for crypt default provider}
  if CryptAcquireContext(@hCryptProvider, nil, nil, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT) then
  begin
    {create hash-object MD5}
    if CryptCreateHash(hCryptProvider, CALG_SHA1, 0, 0, @hHash) then
    begin

      {get hash from password}
      if CryptHashData(hHash, PByte(Key), Length(Key), 0) then
      begin

        // hHash is now a hash of the provided key, (SHA1)
        // Now we derive a key for it
        hPubKey := 0;

        FillChar(keyBlob, SizeOf(keyBlob), 0);
        keyBlob.keyHeader.bType := PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB;
        keyBlob.keyHeader.bVersion := CUR_BLOB_VERSION;
        keyBlob.keyHeader.aiKeyAlg := CALG_RC4;
        KeyBlob.keySize := KEY_LEN_MAX;

        if(Length(key) < (KEY_LEN_MAX))then
          KeyLen := Length(key)
        else
          KeyLen := KEY_LEN_MAX;
        Move(Key[1], KeyBlob.keyData[0], KeyLen );

        if CryptImportKey(hCryptProvider, @keyBlob, SizeOf(KeyBlob), hPubKey, 0, @hKey) then
        begin

          //hkey now holds our key. So we have do the whole thing over again
          ZeroMemory( @hmac_info, SizeOf(hmac_info) );
          hmac_info.HashAlgid := CALG_SHA1;
          if CryptCreateHash(hCryptProvider, CALG_HMAC, hKey, 0, @hHmacHash) then
          begin
              if CryptSetHashParam( hHmacHash, HP_HMAC_INFO, @hmac_info, 0) then
              begin

                if CryptHashData(hHmacHash, @Value[1], Length(Value), 0) then
                begin
                  if CryptGetHashParam(hHmacHash, HP_HASHVAL, @bHmacHash[0], @dwHmacHashLen, 0) then
                  begin
                    for i := 0 to dwHmacHashLen-1 do
                      Result := Result + IntToHex(bHmacHash[i], 2);
                  end
                  else
                   WriteLn( 'CryptGetHashParam ERROR --> ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)) ;
                end
                else
                  WriteLn( 'CryptHashData ERROR --> ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)) ;
                {destroy hash-object}
                CryptDestroyHash(hHmacHash);
                CryptDestroyKey(hKey);
              end
              else
                WriteLn( 'CryptSetHashParam ERROR --> ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)) ;

          end
          else
            WriteLn( 'CryptCreateHash ERROR --> ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)) ;
        end
        else
          WriteLn( 'CryptDeriveKey ERROR --> ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)) ;

      end;
      {destroy hash-object}
      CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
    end;
    {release the context for crypt default provider}
    CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProvider, 0);
  end;
  Result := AnsiLowerCase(Result);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this @DFriend! Were you able to find a greater then 16 char solution?

Comment: I can't find your second question inquring about the >16 chars, may you please provide that link. I really appreciate you sharing such detailed answer!

Comment: I didnt post a new question in the end as 16 characters served my limited needs (sorry).

Comment: I did get some openssl code to work with keys of any size for another project. I can post it, if it helps but im out and about for a few hours.

Comment: Thanks @dfriend that would be awesome! I actually also tried openssl but got stuck on trying to get visual studio to recognize it, if you can help me with that whenever you have time if you time that would be so great! - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41357374/visual-studio-2015-openssl

Comment: I posted asking if we can get help with greater then 16char here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/41384395/1828637

Comment: When calling CryptImportKey _dwFlags_ should be `CRYPT_IPSEC_HMAC_KEY` to allow import of keys larger than 16 bytes at least with _CALG_RC2_.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the correct result for keys longer than 16 bytes by using OpenSLL. Instead of about 10 Win32 Crypt calls, it was done in three: init, HMAC, and cleanup.

Comment: Can you provide some example code.. Even pseudo code will do. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes may you please provide some sample code. The win stuff is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

I do not work with your functions, so correct me if I am wrong:  I do not see where you compute  HMACSHA1('message', 'key').

After `CryptCreateHash(hCryptProvider, CALG_HMAC, hKey, 0, @hHmacHash)` I guess you are computing HMACSHA1('message', hkey), where the derived key hkey is somehow computed with RC4.

BTW: there is a misleading comment related to MD5 (artefact from old version?)

Comment: Hi, The code sample above is simply the function I call to perform the actual hasing.

I call it as follows

WriteLn( Format('HMACSHA1 of "message" using "key" = [%s]', [Hashhmacsha1( 'key', msg)] ) );

The misleading comment is indeed from a previous version, I'll fix that in the code sample above - thanks for pointing it out!!

Comment: Again: Are you sure that `CryptHashData(hHmacHash, @Value[1], Length(Value), 0)` really uses 'key' and **not** hkey for computing the HMAC? I would guess it uses hkey.

Comment: Yes, it uses hKey for computing the Hash - hKey contains a handle to the key generated by the call to CryptDeriveKey. I'm not sure I follow your point, so please could you expan don what you're saying ?

The code sample is based on the MSDN HMAC Code Sample, [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It seems part of the issue is the key is RC4 encoded before being used, which I can't see being done in other implementations.

Comment: That's what I have supposed. The given test vectors (and more confirmed with
other implementations) use the pure string 'key'. You have to find a way
to use 'key' or the array of bytes  ($6B, $65, $79) directly for the HMAC key, otherwise the results will not match. How this can be done, I cannot tell you because I do not use these MS functions.

Comment: i've managed to find an alterative way of generating the hKey handle, using plaintext, but it limits the size of the keys to 16 bytes. Yet every other implementation i can find allows longer keys... ideas ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. But now you that you know the source of
the problems, you may ask another questions, how to do that.  
BTW: Googling pops up some similar questions without  
a definite answer.

Comment: Yeah, I hit a similiar deadend in my googling efforts as well - seems no one is quite sure what to do.

I did manage to get it up and running as expected, but as previously mentioned - the key size is limited, unlike other implementations I've seen or tested it against.