# Visual Studio 2015 OpenSSL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, openssl

I was trying to `#include <openssl/hmac.h>` in my C++ app. So I tried to follow this instructiosn:

http://www.askyb.com/windows/compiling-and-installing-openssl-for-32-bit-windows/comment-page-1/#comment-47532

I succesfully did this much:

- Create a new folder C:\openssl-1.0.1c
- Downloaded 1.1.0c from github - https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tree/91eaf079b7430cb4ebb7f3ccabe74aa383b27c4e
- Extracted it to `C:\openssl-1.0.1c`
- I downloaded and installedinstall ActiveState Perl
- Added `C:\perl\bin` to my path like this in my screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JWW9.png
- Create a new folder `C:\openssl-1.0.1c-bin`
- Opened command prompt with Win+R then typed `cmd`
- Then pasted with quotes `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"`, which is the correct path, it exists on my system
- It ran then I did `perl Configure VC-WIN32 no-asm – -prefix=C:\openssl-1.0.1c-bin` (no quotes), it told me to `ppm install dmake` to get `nmake` so I did that - https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6BrD.png
- I typed `nmake` as per this issue - https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1002 - it is no longer possible to do `nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak`, this took like 15minutes
- It worked then I did `nmake test`

All tests passed, however my `C:\openssl-1.0.1c-bin` directory is empty and doing `#include <openssl/hmac.h>` is not working my visual studio.

I'm a newbie to writing c++.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a step at the end, Run this command “nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak install”. It will copy all the libraries to C:\openssl-1.0.1g-bin.

If you do that it will work as expected.  I just tried it locally with windows 7 and visual studio 2015 and it worked fine.

The warning about nmake is spurious you can continue using nmake ok.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't try it but accepted it. I will try it and let you know how it goes. :)